# How to use a Weka model to print prediction in an excel column

Tags: excel, weka

I would like to use the classification model I've created in Weka in excel. Is that possible?
The classification model uses the SimpleLogistic function. In Weka, it prints out the prediction for each row in a beautiful way. I would like to have exactly those predictions as a column in excel without opening Weka.
Is it possible to export some sort of formula in Weka, that I can use it excel?

Weka printed out some the following formula, but apparently it is not the prediction.
Class Problem :

```
-7.15 + 
[A] * -143.53 +
[B] * -15.74 +
[D] * 176.96 +
[E] * -1.67
```

Class NoProblem :

```
-7.15 + 
[A] * -143.53 +
[B] * -15.74 +
[D] * 176.96 +
[E] * 1.67
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Weka models are Java objects and need to be used from a Java context.

Apart from LinearRegression, most models cannot be easily expressed with simple formulas, hence there is no export of models to spreadsheet applications like LibreOffice Calc or MS Excel available.

If you just want the predictions, but in a format that is easier to use in a spreadsheet application, then you could output them in a CSV file:

- on the *Classify* tab
- click on the *More options* button
- select *CSV* for *Output predictions*
- specify the CSV file you want to store the predictions in
- check *suppressOutput* if you do not want the predictions to be output in the user interface as well (they will still be output to the file)
- click on the *Start* button

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I found using CLI with a little bash script, it can be generated faster. https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/making_predictions/